# Set MS Project durations to default to edays

Tags: ms-project

(newbie alert)  How might I set the duration column in MS Project 2013 to default to edays?  Or, how can I get the same effect with a custom column?

I tried this

[how to show calendar days](http://blog.jackvinson.com/archives/2009/11/05/tech_tip_how_to_show_calendar_day_duration_in_ms_project.html)

```
Int(DateDiff("n",[Start],[Finish])/(24*60)+0.9)
```

however, the column doesn't roll up to parent items, just works for the lowest child task in an activity.

It seems like there should be a setting in Project to just use edays (if I could find it)

Answer (score 0):

In Custom Fields select the "Use Formula" radio button in the "Calculation for task and group summary rows".  What I can't figure out is when I add the +0.9 to the end of the formula I get "#ERROR".

Comment: I tried several of the Use Formula approaches and could not get them to work, so used this workaround, which was to set the Calendar to "24 Hours Calendar", which I believe is a standard Calendar that also has all days as work days.  Then when I set a Task duration count, it correctly equates to elapsed days.